# Develop Window phone app in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am very new to windows phone app development. I have visual studio 2010 and I want to develop windows phone app in it. So is there any plugin, by which I am able to develop windows phone app in existing visual studio 2010?

While I googgled I find windows phone SDK with visual studio  2012 express.But I want to develop window phone app with my existing visual studio 2010.Is it possible,if yes then how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to develop apps for Windows Phone 7.5 and 7.8 phones, you can do so with the help of Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone SDK. But, remember by this you cannot develop apps for WP 8.0. (By the way, your 7.5/7.8 apps will work on WP 8 devices also, but the point is you cannot use the 8.0 specific apps)

And for developing 7.5/7.8 apps, you have to download the following SDK's in the same order.

[WP 7.1 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27570)

[WP 7.1.1 SDK Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29233)

[WP 7.8 SDK Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36474)